# How to add username and password based uthentication to kubernetes dashboard using helm and terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, rbac, vultr

I have this terraform config for deploying a kubernetes dashboard to my cluster on [VKE](https://www.vultr.com/kubernetes/).

```
resource "helm_release" "my-kubernetes-dashboard" {
  name = "my-kubernetes-dashboard"

  repository = "https://kubernetes.github.io/dashboard/"
  chart      = "kubernetes-dashboard"
  namespace  = "default"

  set {
    name  = "service.type"
    value = "ClusterIP"
  }

  set {
    name  = "protocolHttp"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "service.externalPort"
    value = 80
  }

  set {
    name  = "replicaCount"
    value = 1
  }

  set {
    name  = "rbac.clusterReadOnlyRole"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name  = "rbac.clusterAdminRole"
    value = "true"
  }

  set {
    name = "rbac.create"
    value = "true"
  }
}
```

Right now kubernetes dashboard pops right up without asking for any password with full permissions. What do I need to add/change to make kubernetes dashboard require a username and password to login.